# Jquery FileApi returing open is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fileapi

I am using [FileApi](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?7a104fSp) (**See Userpic + crop Demo** ) to Crop Image Before upload. but as soon as i select image file from computer, I got a error

```
$(...).modal(...).open is not a function
```

JS:

```
     <link href="~/Content/statics/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jcrop/jquery.Jcrop.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Content/FileAPI/FileAPI.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/FileAPI/FileAPI.exif.js"></script>

<script src="~/Content/jcrop/jquery.fileapi.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/jcrop/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Content/statics/jquery.modal.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#userpic').fileapi({

            url: '@Url.Action("upl","Home")',
            accept: 'image/*',
            imageSize: { minWidth: 200, minHeight: 200 },
            elements: {
                active: { show: '.js-upload', hide: '.js-browse' },
                preview: {
                    el: '.js-preview',
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200
                },
                progress: '.js-progress'
            },
            onSelect: function (evt, ui) {
                var file = ui.files[0];
                if (!FileAPI.support.transform) {
                    alert('Your browser does not support Flash :(');
                }
                else if (file) {
                    debugger;
                    $('#popup').modal({
                        closeOnEsc: true,
                        closeOnOverlayClick: false,
                        onOpen: function (overlay) {
                            $(overlay).on('click', '.js-upload', function () {
                                $.modal().close();
                                $('#userpic').fileapi('upload');
                            });
                            $('.js-img', overlay).cropper({
                                file: file,
                                bgColor: '#fff',
                                maxSize: [$(window).width() - 100, $(window).height() - 100],
                                minSize: [200, 200],
                                selection: '90%',
                                onSelect: function (coords) {
                                    $('#userpic').fileapi('crop', file, coords);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).open();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

It is my html

```
<div id="userpic" class="userpic">
    <div class="js-preview userpic__preview"></div>
    <div class="btn btn-success js-fileapi-wrapper">
        <div class="js-browse">
            <span class="btn-txt">Choose</span>
            <input type="file" name="filedata">
        </div>
        <div class="js-upload" style="display: none;">
            <div class="progress progress-success"><div class="js-progress bar"></div></div>
            <span class="btn-txt">Uploading</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So check what is `open`? `undefined` or what?

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the modal file(s).

See the following example of jQuery FileApi:

https://github.com/RubaXa/jquery.fileapi/blob/master/index.html

I see there:

```
<script src="./FileAPI/FileAPI.min.js"></script>
And more files..... And then:
<script src="./statics/jquery.modal.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems relevant but then in this case shouldn't `.modal()` returns an error? PS: i don't know this plugin, just wondering

Comment: @A.Wolff $(...).modal(...).open is not a function. Without the required includes, modal is undefined. open() is in that case not a function of modal.

Comment: But then, this wouldn't throw this error: `$(...).modal(...).open is not a function`

Comment: @HenriSchellingerhout: see my updated question . I have included all the files, But now I'm getting another error. `el is undefined`

Comment: @A.Wolff: See the JS. I have put a debugger. But Debugger is not reaching at that point.

Comment: @AmitKumar, you mean the 'el' of these code: el: '.js-preview'?

Comment: @A.Wolff You're right ... But strange if 'modal' is known, without the required includes.

Comment: @HenriSchellingerhout: yes. It's Not showing Model to Crop my image.

Comment: @AmitKumar Are you sure that all files are included en available (you can check that easy by tools as Firebug or de developer tools of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.

Comment: @HenriSchellingerhout: yes. You can also see .I have included all the files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85503/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-henri-schellingerhout).